Laravel Facades Usage, \DB vrs use DB vrs use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
We are supporting a Laravel code base where the Database Facade is accessed using the following:

\DB
DB, with a use DB;
DB, with a use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

We would like to pick one and use it through the codebase.  Is there a functional advantage or difference to using one over the others?
We have tried all three, and each seems to work.
